# Customizing colour bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I am trying to create a customized colour bar for a data series with only values of 20, 21, 22, 23, and 24. I would like the values to have a colour of my choice and not the ones available in the `cmap`.

When I use the `'jets'` `cmap`, I get the following image

[image]

I would like it to be for example,

```
20 - Dark Green
21 - Light Green
22 - Yellow
23 - Blue
24 - Red
```

I am using the following code:

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, autoscale_on=1)
ax1.set_xticklabels(np.arange(-82.,-35.,3))
ax1.set_yticklabels(np.arange(-26.,12.,3))
cax1 = plt.matshow(LC2001, interpolation='nearest', origin='lower',fignum=0, 
cmap='jet')
fig1.colorbar(cax1)
```

where LC2001 is the data series with 37 X 49 values.

Comment: There is an example [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot  DavidG